# Lubuntu core iso install

Tags: lubuntu

When I inquired about installing Lubuntu core, people commenting here said it does not exist. However, I have been advised by people at the Official Lubuntu website to use that version.

Comment: Go with what the people on the "official lubuntu website" says. I do not see a "lubuntu core" on the website, can you clarify what you are looking for ? https://lubuntu.net/

Comment: See also https://docs.lubuntu.net/lubuntu_installation_on_old_computers.html and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/MinimalInstall

Comment: Nowadays [lubuntu.me](https://lubuntu.me/) is the official Lubuntu website. You can find iso files and checksums for standard Ubuntu and Ubuntu community flavours via [releases.ubuntu.com](http://releases.ubuntu.com/) and Ubuntu `mini.iso` files via [cdimages.ubuntu.com/netboot](http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/netboot/)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What’s your question? What are you trying to achieve? (Please [edit] your post when you want to clarify something or add information. It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons.) Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

### Lubuntu Core meta-package

Lubuntu Core is a meta-package (that helps you install the packages that will make a basic operating system into Lubuntu Core. There is no corresponding iso file. This is different from Xubuntu, where a Xubuntu team member has uploaded [unofficial Xubuntu Core iso files](https://unit193.net/xubuntu/core/).

- You need a wired connection (ethernet) to the internet for this to work.

### BIOS mode - start from Ubuntu `mini.iso`

I would install it like this (in BIOS mode),

- Download an Ubuntu [**`mini.iso`**](http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/netboot/) iso file alias a Netboot iso file.
- Check that it matches the corresponding md5sum.
- Create a boot USB/CD drive (for example by cloning).
- Boot into the USB/CD drive and use the text mode installer to install a basic operating system that works in text mode.
- Reboot and login in text mode (in the basic operating system).
- Run the following commands to install Lubuntu Core

  ```
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt full-upgrade
  sudo apt install lubuntu-core
  ```
- Now, when you reboot, you should have Lubuntu Core, which looks pretty much like standard Lubuntu, but without several program packages. So select and install the application program packages that you want :-)

### UEFI mode - start from Ubuntu Server iso file

- If you must install Lubuntu Core in UEFI mode, you can start from an old style Ubuntu Server iso with the Debian installer. The procedure looks pretty much the same as with `mini.iso`, and it works in both BIOS mode and UEFI mode.